# how can i mock a dynamically loaded, virtual module in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, virtual, jestjs

I have a virtual javascript file in a Jest unit test with the path '/widgets/1.0.js'. I have mocked the fs module to simulate its existence.

Now i would like to dynamically load it to invoke a method 'foo()'. I thought it would be a case of using a virtual mock:

```
index.test.js
    jest.mock('/widgets/1.0.js', () => {foo: jest.fn(() => {console.log('foo!')})}, {virtual: true});
```

The code which calls the mock:

```
index.js
    let module = require('/widgets/1.0.js');
    module.foo();
```

When i run the test:

```
Cannot find module '/widgets/1.0.js' from 'index.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:151:17)
      at processWidgets (src/index.js:115:2418)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/index.test.js:99:73)
```

I think it should be possible. Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a problem with the module path. This works:

```
index.test.js
jest.mock('1.0', () => {
  return {
    foo: () => {return 42;}
  }
}, {virtual: true});

index.js
const module = require('1.0');
   let retval = module.foo();
   console.log('retval: ', retval);
```

If i use '/widgets/1.0' it does not. Hope it helps..

Comment: keep in mind that in your first implementation the mock function is not returning anything, maybe that's the error